# How to create the new projects and how to send the bug reports through Email in "Gemini" tool?

Tags: testing, bug-tracking, gemini

I have installed the "Gemini" tool in my system. Now i am not getting any option for creating my own project when I am in manager account or in personal account. It has three projects by default named as "Help Desk, Company Intranet, Integrated Marketing Solution". I am not able to edit those project names also through manager account or personal account. Is there any option in this tool for create new projects.

And in this tool how to send the bug reports to developer's through Email. Can any one suggest me about the same.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you have logged in as a Gemini Administrator then you can create projects via the Administration -> Projects option.

Not sure I get what you mean about sending DEVs emails -- set up project email alerts perhaps?

If you still get stuck then I recommend you drop the guys @ Countersoft an email as their support rocks.